# Realloc inside a function - corrupted size vs. prev_size

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, realloc

I've decided to learn C and C++ but Im struggling with a simple task and cant get my head around it. I would really appreciate the help.

In one of my functions i make a pointer * linesLenght and I call another function to allocate memory and fill array. In one of the functions there's a reallocation that happens 1-3 times. On the first time everything goes right. But when reallocating on the 2nd try, i get a corrupted size vs. prev_size error.

Code:

1st. function

```
char * wordWrap (int width, const char * src ){
ulong len = strlen(src);
ulong lines = getLines(width,len);
int * linesLenght = getLinesLen(&lines, src, len, width);
... }
```

2nd function

```
int * getLinesLen(ulong * lines, const char * src, ulong srcLen, int maxLine){
    int * linesLen = malloc((*lines) * sizeof(int));
    ulong counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < srcLen; i++)
    {
            ///other hidden logic....
            if(counter == *lines)
            {
                printf("out! Must resize\n");
                resizeLinesArr(counter + 1, &linesLen);
                *lines += 1;
            }
    }
    *lines = counter;
    return linesLen;
}
```

3rd functin (HERE I GET THE ERROR)

```
void resizeLinesArr(ulong arrLen, int ** arr)
{
    int * tmp = realloc(*arr, arrLen * sizeof(int));

    if(tmp == NULL)
    {
        printf("realloc problem\n");
        free(*arr);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        *arr = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give more info about the exact error you get?

Comment: exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT) //////  *** Error in `/home/stepnlub/....': corrupted size vs. prev_size: 0x00000000024db300 ***

Comment: Perhaps you are corrupting the heap with a wild pointer?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: You are writing over the bounds of the allocated buffer in some code you did not show here, probably in the "other hidden logic"

Answer (score 8):

This error:

```
corrupted size vs. prev_size
```

is an error that malloc (or realloc) prints when its internal record-keeping variables have been corrupted. The problem is almost certainly not in the line that calls realloc. At some point, you either:

1. Write past the end of a heap-allocated buffer, or before the beginning.
2. Continue to use a pointer after you `free()` it.

This sort of thing is usually pretty hard to track down. I suggest that you try running the program using valgrind. First, add `-g` to the list of options you pass to the compiler. This turns on debugging information, which lets Valgrind give you line numbers instead of just function names.

Then run your program like this:

```
valgrind ./your_program
```

Valgrind will look at every memory access and check if it violates the two rules I described above.